# difference method java using enum types

Tags: java, enums

I wish to write a method that can return the difference in value of 2 cards.
Im confused as I'm learning enums and not sure of the most efficient way to implement it.

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
public enum Rank {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, 
                    JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE}
public enum Suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES}

public static int difference(Card c){

}
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Oridinal may be useful for you assuming order is incremental http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()

Comment: you need the enum to return an int, and then a method to calcuate the difference between two ints. Its not really that hard, give it a go ...

Comment: I think we need more information.  I can imagine how you would find the difference in value between two number cards but how are you defining the value of Kings, Queens, etc.?  Also, you have not described the `Card` class.

Comment: @Nambari FYI escape parens with "\" in comment links. Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: Thats a good point. I assumed enums gave themselves default values based on their declared positions... I'm even more confused now ha.
Yes i know its not difficult but i am a newbie.

Comment: @PaulBellora: Not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @Nambari Sorry, should've been more clear. Basically the anchor in your link doesn't work cause the parens at the end weren't picked up. To solve that in the future you could use a named link, e.g. \[name\]\(link\) and then escape the parens in the link with "\". See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @PaulBellora: Thanks for tip. Will follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public enum Rank {ACE(1), TWO(2); /* obviously add the other values*/
    private int value  ;
    Rank(int value){
        this.value = value;
    };
    public int getValue(){
       return this.value;
    }

    public int calcDifference(Rank rank){
        return getValue() - rank.getValue();
    }

};
```

which can then be called like so :

```
Rank rankAce =  Rank.ACE;
System.out.println(rankAce.calcDifference(Rank.TWO));
```

You could remove the int value and just use ordinal, but this way gives you a bit of flexibility.

Comment: `calcDifference` can throws `NullPointerException`

Comment: What about `rankAce.calcDifference(null)`?

Comment: @PaulVargas sheesh, ok fair enough

Comment: Ok i've edited all my code above in the original post. 
Your method doesn't seem to work for me.... (I'm probably doing something dumb)

Comment: @shardy You have made the difference method static, when it references an instance variable. My example does not do this.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Yes i know, your method is fine. But my method needs to be static apparently. And i'm wondering how to implement a static method that calculates the difference. I should of mentioned that in my original post. It slipped my mind.

Comment: you can;t reference this from a static, so it shoudl take two ranks as  parameters

Comment: @NimChimpsky How would you implement it by passing it 2 parameters?

Comment: @shardy you'll have to do a bit of thinking for yself I'm afraid; I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: @PaulVargas Out of curiosity, how would you handle a `null` argument?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to define a value of a card is to add thirteen times the suit to the rank, or to add four times the rank to the suit:

```
public int faceValue(Card c) {
    return 13*c.getSuit().ordinal()+c.getRank().ordinal();
}
```

or

```
public int faceValue(Card c) {
    return 4*c.getRank().ordinal()+c.getSuit().ordinal();
}
```

Both ways produce numbers from `0` to `51`, inclusive.

With `faceValue` in hand, you can define the difference function as follows:

```
public static int faceValueDifference(Card left, Card right){
    return left.faceValue()-right.faceValue();
}
```

Comment: I have never played a card game that values the king of spades 52.

Comment: @NimChimpsky The `faceValue` that this example calculates is purely notional, i.e. suitable for ordering cards without ambiguities. Neither of the two functions has anything to do with any particular card game that I know.