# Static method to return enum in java

Tags: java, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference method java using enum types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272727/difference-method-java-using-enum-types)

Is it possible to calculate the difference between the values of 2 enum types using a static method? Where the enums represent a deck. (i.e. Two(2) of Spades, Queen(10) of Hearts = 8).

```
public enum Rank {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, 
                    JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE}
public enum Suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES}
```

I want the method to return the difference in ranks between two cards...
Not sure how to approach/efficiently implement this. Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible. See the ordinal() for enum.

Comment: Is it a school work or something? This is the third post relative to cards enums today...

Comment: @dounyy or the same person asking the same question three times. ;)

Comment: @dounyy They were all my questions. The first one got off topic and the second one didn't help me. Sorry. I'm only just grasping Enums

Comment: @qwertyRocker Please do not do this again, that's a very efficient way to annoy the community. Not only you won't have an answer to you question, but also you may reduce the will of the community to give its help for "simple" questions like yours. One post is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static int diff(Rank first, Rank second){
    return Math.abs(first.ordinal() - second.ordinal() + someDefaultValue);
 }
```

Comment: @qwertyRocker an `enum` is just a class, and as such it can have fields, a non-empty constructor, etc. Rather than relying on `ordinal()`, you may want to consider manually assigning each enum a value via a constructor: `QUEEN(10)`, etc. This way, you can also have duplicate values (an ordinal is unique within each enum type). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html, and especially the Planet enum (which shows how to declare fields, methods, constructors).